# ASP.NET MVC Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Собственно, уже второй день бьюсь над этой проблемой. Выдает "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations. Dependencies may exist due to foreign key constraints, model requirements, or store-generated values." при попытке сохранить изменения в контексте базы данных. Вот код:

```
        var forum = ctx.Forums.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ForumID);

        if (forum == null)
            return View("~");

        var userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        var user = mgr.FindById(userID);

        var topic = new Topic();
        topic.Parent = forum;
        topic.Caption = model.Caption;
        topic.SubCaption = model.SubCaption;
        topic.TopicStarter = user;

        var message = new TopicMessage();
        message.Date = DateTime.Now;
        message.User = user;
        message.Parent = topic;
        message.Text = model.Text;

        topic.Messages.Add(message);
        topic.LastMessage = message;

        forum.Topics.Add(topic);
        forum.LastTopic = topic;

        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Классы, которые использовал http://pastebin.com/s6gwQsmM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что чтобы сохранить в базу `message` вам нужен идентификатор `topic` (чтобы записать его во внешний ключ для связи `Parent`). А для сохранения `topic` вам надо знать идентификатор `message`...

Для решения проблемы разбейте сохранение на две части. Сначала создайте топик, присоединенный к форуму, но без сообщений, сохраните - а потом уже создавайте первое сообщение в нем. Можно использовать транзакцию, чтобы при ошибе в базе не остался топик без сообщений.

---

Альтернативный вариант - изменить схему БД так, чтобы ошибка не возникала. Например, можно генерировать первичный ключ не на стороне базы, а на стороне приложения. Или убрать свойство LastMessage.